# Attempting to use nonexistant memory in MIPS while checking peggle

Tags: assembly, out-of-memory, mips

First of all, I know its a bad question name. Im not really sure what the name should be, since it requires context to understand. feel free to edit if you think of a better one

My assignment is to create peg solitaire in mips. The problem I am having is in implementing the brute force check I have to create that will check to see if there are any more legal moves on the board.

The board is a 10x10 block of memory. each space where the board would have a peg, the ASCII value for X is stored.

the problem is that to check for all legal moves, I have to check for

pseudocode

```
while iterator < 100
if iterator point is valid
     if move from iterator to iterator -20 valid
          result = true
          exit function
     else if move from iterator to iterator +20 valid
          result = true
          exit function
     else if move from iterator to iterator -2 valid
          result = true
          exit function
     else if move from iterator to iterator +2 valid
          result = true
          exit function
     else
          iterator = iterator+1
else
     iterator = iterator+1
```

the problem Im running into is that when I check the 4 valid jumps iteratively like that, some of them go outside of the allotted memory for the board ex: 2-20, or 99 +2

which is triggering an Attempt to use non-existent memory error.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: How about some conditional jumps :)

Comment: well thats tricky in assembly... If Im honest I don't really understand memory very well. As I understand it, the range that Im checking isnt actually 0-100 its some random memory address assigned to me by the code and then the address +1,+2+3....+99. Can I actually check for 0 as if that were the number?

Comment: Check the index/iterator - if it is out of range, don't dereference it.

Comment: I can check for x<100 sure but arent all ints in MIPS unsigned? as soon as I go below 0 it instantly turns into some insanely high number instead of a negative one

Comment: There are signed and unsigned comparisons, but using the unsigned one you even get to cover both cases with the `x<100` check ... how awesome is that? As you said, you will get an "insanely high number" which is going to be `>100`

Comment: wait, are you telling me to do the addition using addiu, or to do the comparison using sltiu?

Comment: Both, although signed addition should also work, you are not going to get a signed overflow.